# Python set value in Dataframe to Nan Based on Value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan

I am trying to set the values of certain columns in a dataframe to Nan based on the value of the cell. I am having problems getting it to work. Here is what I have tried.
I need to set all cells where the windspeed is < -200 to NaN.

```
filterA.loc[filterA['WindSpeedMPH'] < -200, 'WindSpeedMPH']   ==   NaN
filterA.loc[filterA['WindSpeedMPH'].le -200, 'WindSpeedMPH']  == Nan
```

but it doesn;t'work. I ma sure it is something fairly simple but I can't figure it out and haven't found the answer googling it.
I have tried multiple

Answer (score 0):

We can try `mask`

```
filterA['WindSpeedMPH'].mask(filterA['WindSpeedMPH'] < -200, inplace=True)
```

To fix your code

```
filterA.loc[filterA['WindSpeedMPH'] < -200, 'WindSpeedMPH'] = np.nan
```

Comment: That worked had to convert it to an int from an object

Comment: @JimRyan glad it work , yes since you have two type and mixed datatype for one col, so that should be object

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to do it as simple as this:

```
filterA.loc[filterA['WindSpeedMPH'] < -200, 'WindSpeedMPH'] = np.nan
```

See documentation [here](https://datatofish.com/if-condition-in-pandas-dataframe/) for 5 ways to apply an IF condition in pandas DataFrame.

Comment: Now I am getting this error 'TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int''